# Failed to build brotlipy when I tried to install brotlipy in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I tried to install brotlipy with PyCharm in MacOS 13.4 with M1 chip, shows error like this:

```
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
Collecting brotlipy==0.7.0
  Using cached https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/d9/91/bc79b88590e4f662bd40a55a2b6beb0f15da4726732efec5aa5a3763d856/brotlipy-0.7.0.tar.gz (413 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from brotlipy==0.7.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->brotlipy==0.7.0) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: brotlipy
  Building wheel for brotlipy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for brotlipy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for brotlipy
Failed to build brotlipy

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [115 lines of output]
      /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/brotli
      copying src/brotli/build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/brotli
      copying src/brotli/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/brotli
      copying src/brotli/brotli.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/brotli
      running build_clib
      building 'libbrotli' library
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/common
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/common/dictionary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/common/dictionary.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/dec/bit_reader.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/bit_reader.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/dec/decode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/decode.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/dec/huffman.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/huffman.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/dec/state.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/state.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/backward_references.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/backward_references.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/backward_references_hq.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/backward_references_hq.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/bit_cost.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/bit_cost.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/block_splitter.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/block_splitter.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/brotli_bit_stream.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/brotli_bit_stream.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/cluster.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/cluster.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/dictionary_hash.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/dictionary_hash.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/encode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/encode.o
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:747:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          BrotliWipeOutMemoryManager(m);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1157:25: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                              ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1181:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1188:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1201:31: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                    ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1234:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1244:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1264:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1269:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1280:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      10 warnings generated.
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:747:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          BrotliWipeOutMemoryManager(m);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1157:25: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                              ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1181:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1188:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1201:31: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                    ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1234:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1244:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1264:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1269:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      libbrotli/enc/encode.c:1280:29: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            if (BROTLI_IS_OOM(m)) goto oom;
                                  ^~~~~~~~
      10 warnings generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/entropy_encode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/entropy_encode.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/histogram.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/histogram.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/literal_cost.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/literal_cost.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/memory.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/memory.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/metablock.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/metablock.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/static_dict.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/static_dict.o
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Ilibbrotli/include -Ilibbrotli/ -Isrc/brotli -c libbrotli/enc/utf8_util.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/utf8_util.o
      /usr/bin/xcrun ar rcs build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/liblibbrotli.a build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/common/dictionary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/bit_reader.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/decode.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/huffman.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/dec/state.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/backward_references.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/backward_references_hq.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/bit_cost.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/block_splitter.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/brotli_bit_stream.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/cluster.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/compress_fragment_two_pass.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/dictionary_hash.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/encode.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/entropy_encode.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/histogram.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/literal_cost.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/memory.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/metablock.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/static_dict.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/libbrotli/enc/utf8_util.o
      warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive library: build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/liblibbrotli.a will be fat and ar(1) will not be able to operate on it
      ranlib build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/liblibbrotli.a
      /usr/local/bin/ranlib: build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/liblibbrotli.a: invalid operation
      error: command '/usr/local/bin/ranlib' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for brotlipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for brotlipy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?